# PHP APC user cache getting cleared automatically

Tags: php, caching, apc

Set up:
PHP 5.3 + FastCGI + suExec

We've noticed that APC **user** cache is getting cleared automatically and that too very frequently (within 3-4 minutes).

But we are unable to find out the reason.

usr_ttl  is set to 7200. Apc.php shows that only 25% of available 256MB is ever used. So its not out of memory/ttl problem.

Somewhere it was mentioned that FastCGI processes do not share APC user cache among them. Could it be the reason?

Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried to set also `apc.ttl=7200` ?

Comment: I think apc.ttl should not matter as 75% memory is available all time.

Comment: yes you are right, then check the uptime.. maybe it restarts and that clears the keys